# How can I create a month year variable?

Tags: datetime, time-series, stata, panel

I have monthly trade data from Jan 2002 to Dec 2013. But these are string variables. I want to create a month year time variable in Stata from 2002m1 to 2013m12. How can I do this?

I have tried using the `mdy()` function, but it creates a continuous time series. I want to create a panel.

Answer (score 0):

The `mdy()` function -- think `m`onth, `d`ay, `y`ear -- creates a numeric daily date variable from string input. It does nothing else. There is no sense in which it creates a continuous time series.

To get a numeric monthly date variable from a string monthly date variable, use `monthly()`. If your variable held values like `"Jan 2002"`, then this would work. Again, there are no side effects for any other variables. `

This is all documented in detail. Start with `help datetime`.

```
. clear

. set obs 1
Number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1.

. gen smdate = "Jan 2002"

. gen nmdate = monthly(smdate, "MY")

. format nmdate %tm

. list

     +-------------------+
     |   smdate   nmdate |
     |-------------------|
  1. | Jan 2002   2002m1 |
     +-------------------+

. summarize

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      smdate |          0
      nmdate |          1         504           .        504        504
```

To declare your dataset as panel data, see `help xtset` or `help tsset`.

Comment: Hey, the string variable which I currently have is of the form "2002m1" - "2013m12". When I use the `monthly` function it creates a vector of all missing values.

Comment: I guess that is because you didn't read the help carefully. `di monthly("2002m1", "YM")` works as would an equivalent `generate` statement.  If you tried `"MY"` that was the wrong way round.

Comment: This worked out! I appreciate the input. I use `gen time = monthly(date,"YM")` and `format time %tm`